# Hot to get state from Redux RTK mutation in another component

Tags: redux, toolkit, rtk-query

Hey i'm new to RTK toolkit and **just trying to access state from isolated component to store state from mutation**, so i can skip passing them to that component.

I can see the result from mutation in redux store behind the cashe key, but how to access the store data from isolated component?

I read the documentation at least twice and saw that if it's QUERY i can pass useGet** hook with the same args and could get the result. But my case is to access result from mutation (POST query).

Just in case i can create selector to the whole state:

`export const selectSubmitStatus = (state) => state[createApi.reducerPath];`
and possibly manual filter current item, but it could be easier to access mutation *submitState* with selector and passing cashe key or?

Simmilar problem [here described](https://issueexplorer.com/issue/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/1458)

Comment: Well a few times later i found that this is not possible for now. There is possible workarround with ```useMyMutation({ fixedCacheKey: "myCacheKey" })``` described here from the author:  https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/pull/1477

Comment: `fixedCacheKey` will be included in the next release of RTK, but until then you need to write that data "to the side" into a slice - or just use the CI build from that issue you linked there.